# prosilica GC650C

Tags: ros, prosilica-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying to use a prosilica GC650C.

I follow the instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/prosilica_camera/Tutorials

The camera works, except for a small detail - images are in grayscale and the camera should give color images.

I launched reconfigure_gui but could not find any parameter regarding video format.

Can anyone help?

regards

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12649/prosilica-gc650c/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The prosilica output is in Bayer format; you need to run image_proc to debayer it to produce a color image. See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1